# YCbCr Video Input STM32F746

Tags: image-processing, stm32, stm32f7, ycbcr

I am working on STM32F746 based custom board which is integrated with LCD and a ADV7180 video decoder IC.

I Configured the ADV7180 to run in the free run mode. Getting the Camera data using DCMI to a specified buffer.

I am trying to Convert the YCbCr 4:2:2 data to the RBG data. I am getting the Line Events. .
From the Live events I am executing the below piece of code to convert it to the RGB and then load the it to the LCD using ARGB888.

LCD_FRAME_BUFFER 0xC0000000
LCD_FRAME_BUFFER_LAYER1 0xC0130000
CAMERA_FRAME_BUFFER 0xC0260000

```
void LCD_LL_Test(void *pSrc, void *pDst, uint32_t lcd_offset, uint32_t cam_offset)
{ 

  uint32_t * pTempDest = (uint32_t *)(LCD_FRAME_BUFFER_LAYER1);
  uint32_t * pTempSource = (uint32_t *)(CAMERA_FRAME_BUFFER+cam_offset);

  uint32_t * pFinalDest = (uint32_t *)(LCD_FRAME_BUFFER+lcd_offset);
  uint32_t * pFinalSource = (uint32_t *)(LCD_FRAME_BUFFER_LAYER1);

  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < (480/2) ; i++ ){
    uint32_t te =  *pTempSource;   
    // CB Y1 CR , RESULT  
    toRGB( (te>>0),(te>>8),(te>>16) ,(uint32_t *)pTempDest);
    pTempDest++;
    // CB Y2 CR , RESULT 
    toRGB( (te>>0),(te>>24),(te>>16) ,(uint32_t *)pTempDest);
    pTempDest++;
    pTempSource++;
  }
  static DMA2D_HandleTypeDef hDma2dEval;  

  hDma2dEval.Init.Mode         = DMA2D_M2M_PFC;
  hDma2dEval.Init.ColorMode    = DMA2D_OUTPUT_ARGB8888;
  hDma2dEval.Init.OutputOffset = 0;     

  hDma2dEval.LayerCfg[1].AlphaMode = DMA2D_NO_MODIF_ALPHA;
  hDma2dEval.LayerCfg[1].InputAlpha = 0xFF;
  hDma2dEval.LayerCfg[1].InputColorMode = DMA2D_RGB888;
  hDma2dEval.LayerCfg[1].InputOffset = 0;

  hDma2dEval.Instance = DMA2D; 

  /* DMA2D Initialization */
  if(HAL_DMA2D_Init(&hDma2dEval) == HAL_OK) 
  {
    if(HAL_DMA2D_ConfigLayer(&hDma2dEval, 1) == HAL_OK) 
    {
      if (HAL_DMA2D_Start(&hDma2dEval, (uint32_t)pFinalSource, (uint32_t )(pFinalDest), BSP_LCD_GetXSize()*4, 1) == HAL_OK)
      {
        /* Polling For DMA transfer */  
        HAL_DMA2D_PollForTransfer(&hDma2dEval, 10);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I have initialised the LCD with LCD_FRAME_BUFFER and I am using single layer only.

I am converting the data and copying it to the LCD_FRAME_BUFFER using an intermediate LCD_FRAME_BUFFER_LAYER1 buffer.

DCMI --> CAMERA_FRAME_BUFFER --> CONVERSION --> LCD_FRAME_BUFFER_LAYER1 --> DMA -> LCD_FRAME_BUFFER

But, I am not getting the free run mode screen as BLUE Screen.

[image]

Comment: Few hours ago, three similar questions popped up here: See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540035/stm32-dcmi-using-hardware-syncembedded-sync-cubemx-settingbt656-or-itu656) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724714/stm32h7-dcmi-with-bt-656).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using 0xC0000000 is configured to external RAM, make sure FMC is configured and initialized to self refresh.

Make sure FMC configuration is FMC_SDRAM_CAS_LATENCY_3

Try to add attached function in the end of FMC init

```
void MX_SDRAM_InitEx(void)
{
  __IO uint32_t tmpmrd = 0;

  /* Step 1: Configure a clock configuration enable command */
  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_CLK_ENABLE;
  Command.CommandTarget          =  FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 1;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);

  /* Step 2: Insert 100 us minimum delay */
  /* Inserted delay is equal to 1 ms due to systick time base unit (ms) */
  HAL_Delay(1);

  /* Step 3: Configure a PALL (precharge all) command */
  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_PALL;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 1;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);

  /* Step 4: Configure an Auto Refresh command */
  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_AUTOREFRESH_MODE;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 8;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

  /* Send the command */
  HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);

  /* Step 5: Program the external memory mode register */
  tmpmrd = (uint32_t)SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_1          |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_SEQUENTIAL   |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_3           |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_OPERATING_MODE_STANDARD |\
                     SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_SINGLE;

  Command.CommandMode            = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_LOAD_MODE;
  Command.CommandTarget          = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
  Command.AutoRefreshNumber      = 1;
  Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = tmpmrd;

  /* Send the command */
  HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram1, &Command, SDRAM_TIMEOUT);

  /* Step 6: Set the refresh rate counter */
  /* Set the device refresh rate */
  HAL_SDRAM_ProgramRefreshRate(&hsdram1, REFRESH_COUNT);
}
```